# Rating bar shows more stars when I rotate my application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this weird issue with my rating bar stars.

[This is my app in vertical position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAh1t.jpg)

[This is my app in horizontal position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP9Nf.jpg)

***As you can see the stars completely change***

**This is my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/main"
    tools:context="com.example.draganam.blankapp.Nivo1Activity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="1,0" android:stretchColumns="0,1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/slika0"
                android:src="@drawable/becutan1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="40px" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/slika1"
                android:src="@drawable/blizoo1"
                android:layout_column="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rb0"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1.0"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:scaleX="0.7"
                android:scaleY="0.7"/>

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rb1"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1.0"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:scaleX="0.7"
                android:scaleY="0.7"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/slika2"
                android:src="@drawable/brilijant1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="40px" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/slika3"
                android:src="@drawable/vitaminka1"
                android:layout_column="1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb2"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"/>

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb3"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7"/>
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my java code:**

```
Context ctx2 = this;
String[][] arrayWithInformations = new String[5][];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nivo1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    DatabaseOperations databaseOperations = new DatabaseOperations(ctx2);
    Cursor cursorLogo = databaseOperations.getInformationsForLogos(databaseOperations);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    Integer i = 0;
    if (cursorLogo.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String[] helperArray = {cursorLogo.getString(0),cursorLogo.getString(1),cursorLogo.getString(2),cursorLogo.getString(3),
                    cursorLogo.getString(4),cursorLogo.getString(5)};
            arrayWithInformations[i] = helperArray;
            i++;

        } while (cursorLogo.moveToNext());
    }
    int firstRating = Integer.parseInt(arrayWithInformations[0][4]);
    int secondRating = Integer.parseInt(arrayWithInformations[1][4]);
    int thirdRating = Integer.parseInt(arrayWithInformations[2][4]);
    int fourthRating = Integer.parseInt(arrayWithInformations[3][4]);
    RatingBar rb0 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rb0);
    rb0.setRating(firstRating);
    RatingBar rb1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb1.setRating(secondRating);
    RatingBar rb2 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb2.setRating(thirdRating);
    RatingBar rb3 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb3.setRating(fourthRating);
```

I get the rating values from database file and everything works fine , the stars are ok but when I rotate the phone they are all wrong. I know `that` when u rotate your phone the current activity gets loaded again, but it's the same code and it loads wrong. Maybe it's multiplying the stars.. I may sound funny but I have no idea what is going wrong. Someone please give me a lead..

Comment: can you show us what arrayWithInformations is and where is it initiaized

Comment: i suggest you start debugging with breakpoints. there is nothing wrong with the ui. calculating stars in a problem then i would look at the way you are getting data from sqlite

Comment: I did a debug. Everything looks fine...
Like i said it's coming from SQLite database file. They are right in vertical mode, the first one is 4, then 5,2 and 3. But when I rotate they change and when I rotate back to vertical they are fine again .

Comment: Your loop looks wrong, can you edit your post and insert that extra code in your post? It's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: **This is weird because when I debug it in horizontal position I get the same numbers (4,5,2 and 3) and everything passes with no exceptions, and the stars are wrong**

Comment: It looks like a platform bug, the `TableLayout` is doing something funny to the sizing of the rating bars related to restoring state after rotation.  My suggestion would be to get rid of `TableLayout` and redo your XML using a `RelativeLayout`.  Another option is to make each cell in the `TableRow` a vertical `LinearLayout` that contains both the image and the rating bar underneath it.  I bet that either of these modifications will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Kris, I will try redoing my xml file and see if that will solve my weird problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem !

> android:shrinkColumns="1,0" android:stretchColumns="0,1"

Setting this to the ***TableLayout*** caused this strange issue.

Thanks everyone for your interest in helping me ..